"Understanding Borel Measurability of Continuous Functions on Borel Subsets"
In page 33, section 2.B "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis - Sheldon Axler",
I'm trying to understand a proof  about Borel measurability and would appreciate clarification on the steps involved. The theorem I'm referring to is:
Theorem (2.41): Every continuous real-valued function defined on a Borel subset of $(\mathbb{R})$ is a Borel measurable function.
Here's the proof provided:
Proof:
Suppose $( X \subseteq \mathbb{R})$ is a Borel set and $( f : X \to \mathbb{R} )$ is continuous. To prove that $( f )$ is Borel measurable, fix $( a \in \mathbb{R} )$.
If $( x \in X )$ and ( f(x) > a ), then by the continuity of $( f )$, there exists $( \delta_x > 0 )$ such that
$[ f(y) > a \text{ for all } y \in (x - \delta_x, x + \delta_x) \cap X. ]$
Thus,
$[ f^{-1}((a, \infty)) = \big(\bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}((a, \infty))} (x - \delta_x, x + \delta_x)\big) \cap X. ]$
The union inside the large parentheses above is an open subset of $(\mathbb{R})$; hence its intersection with ( X ) is a Borel set. Thus, we can conclude that $( f^{-1}((a, \infty)) )$ is a Borel set.
Now, using Theorem 2.39, we can conclude that $( f )$ is a Borel measurable function.
Questions:

It is not clear to me if the number of unions in

$f^{-1}((a, \infty)) = \big(\bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}((a, \infty))} (x - \delta, x + \delta)\big) \cap X $
is countable because there could be uncountably many x in $f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ . At least nothing was said about it in the proof.

if the number of union operations is not countable, why the proof is still correct?

Thank you for any clarifications or insights you can provide on this proof!

The union of an arbitrary collection of open sets is open! That part is just topological.

what if the number of union is uncountable. this is not clear?? @Qiaochu Yuan

@saleh Remember that all open sets are borel measurable subsets ;)

@Maxime.
True. but when we have uncountably many unions then we can construct something which is not a borel subset anymore. my concern is uncountability!

I discern only one union in your question. Why do you use the plural form unions? Further the value of the positive $\delta$ depends on $x$ so you should write $\delta_x$ in the notation of the involved union.

@drahb. sure delta depends on x. that was a typo.
but what do you mean by only 1 union?? for every x in f-inverse we do union operation.

@saleh , indeed it is possible to take an uncountable union of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ to get a nonBorel set (just start with a nonBorel set and express it as the union of all its individual points). But you cannot do that with open sets, as the first comment notes. To convince yourself, you can prove the arbitrary union of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is an open subset also (using the epsilon-ball definition of “open set.”) In more general topology spaces, this is just part of the definition of “open set.”

For every $x$ in preimage $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ we have the set $(x-\delta_x,x+\delta_x)$ and we take the union of these sets.

@saleh The union of open sets is open so it is a Borel subset. Then you intersect it with the Borel subset $X$ so you obtain a Borel subset.

@drahb. True. but the total number of time that we should perform union operation is not countable and therefore the problem raised also by Michael might happen

@saleh have you understood that an uncoutable union of open sets is open, hence Borel ?

To clarify: the argument being made is not "$\bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}((a, \infty))} (x - \delta, x + \delta)$ is a countable union of open sets and thus Borel" as you have been arguing. That union is clearly uncountable. The actual argument is that it is a union of open sets and is thus open itself. And because it is open, it is Borel.

Thanks for your comment @paul-sinclair .
Is there any proof for that? is it a Theorem? I have no intuition about uncountably many union of opensets. for countably many union I can understand your argument.

@PaulSinclair for countably many union one can easily prove it e.g by induction. Do you have any clue how can I prove your argument for uncountably many unions?? if you have such a proof or a reference to it please write it as an answer and I will mark it as an accepted one.

@saleh for a general topology, this property is included in the definition of the open sets. In the case of $\mathbb R$ whose topology is simple (metric), you can “prove” it pretty simply. Consider an uncountable union of open sets, and a point $x$ in this union. By definition, there exist a set $U$ in the union that contains $x$, and this set is open since we are considering a union of open sets. So there exists $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ is included in this set and hence is included in the union.

Thanks @Maxime
can you write it please as an answer (not as a comment)

Just a little more information about this. You appear to be thinking of the union of large numbers of sets as being done serially. I.e., you union two, then union that with a third, and so on. But that is not the case. Instead it is defined by: if $\scr S$ is a collection of sets, then $$\bigcup \mathscr S := { x : \exists U \in \mathscr S, x \in U}$$It does not matter how many sets $\scr S$ contains, this handles them all simply and intuitively. Change the $\exists$ to a $\forall$, and you get the intersection.

Here is a sum up of what was said in the previous comments (as requested).
You want to show that $f^{-1}((a, \infty)) = \big(\bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}((a, \infty))} (x - \delta_x, x + \delta_x)\big) \cap X $
is a Borel set.
To do so, you’ll need three facts : (i) intersecting two borel sets gives you one borel set (ii) any open set is a borel set (iii) an arbitrary union of open sets is an open set. With this, you see that the union on the left is an open set since it is an arbitrary union of open sets, so you know that this union is Borel and you deduce by intersecting with $X$ that is a Borel set, that $f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ is a Borel set.
You seem to be familiar with the properties (i) and (ii) so we’ll just talk about the last property.
About this point, if you learn just the very begging of general topology, you’ll see that this property is imposed on the general notion of topology (which means the collection of open sets) on a set, but as you seem to know nothing about it, we will prove it for the case of the open sets of $\mathbb R$.
Consider $\displaystyle U=\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ a union of open sets of $\mathbb R$ indexed by an arbitrary set $I$. Then, let $x\in U$. By definition of the union, it exists $ j\in I$ such that $ x\in U_j$. Now, as $U_j$ is open, you know that it exists $\delta>0$ such that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset U_j$. Since by definition $\displaystyle U_j\subset\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$, you get that $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset\displaystyle U_j\subset\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i=U$, or simply $(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset U$.
Hence $U$ is open as $\forall x\in U,\;\exists \delta>0,\;(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subset U$.

Furthermore, there is something funny with your question, because the union you are considering, can in fact be regarded as a countable union of open sets ! Indeed, as in many situations, we can use the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ !
Indeed, if we choose $(\delta_x)_{x\in f^{-1}((a, \infty)) }$ correctly we have that :
$\displaystyle \bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}((a, \infty))} (x - \delta_x, x + \delta_x)= \bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}((a, \infty))\cap\mathbb Q} (x - \delta_x, x + \delta_x)$
The second union is at most countable (it’s index) as the index has a smaller cardinality than $\mathbb Q$.
For example, setting for all $x\in f^{-1}((a, \infty))$, $\delta_x:=\frac{sup(\{\epsilon>0\;:\;(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset f^{-1}((a, \infty))\})}{2}$ provides us the equality.
The equality comes from the fact that if you choose $x\in f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ that is irrational, you can choose $q\in\mathbb Q$ such that $\lvert q-x\rvert<\frac{\delta_x}{4}$ but density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$. Then, you know that $\delta_q>\lvert q-x\rvert$ by definition of our good family of $\delta$’s since $(q-2 \lvert q-x\rvert, q+ 2\lvert q-x\rvert)\subset f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ (follows directly from the triangular inequality, draw it !).
Then, as $\delta_q> \lvert q-x\rvert$, you know that $x\in(q-\delta_q,q+\delta_q)\subset \bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}((a, \infty))\cap\mathbb Q} (x - \delta_x, x + \delta_x)$ Victory !
